# How do I set Anaconda's python as my default python command?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have both Anaconda and Python 2.7 installed on my Windows machine. Right now the command "python" points to Python 2.7, but I'd like instead for it to point to Anaconda's python. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `PATH` is pointing to the original Python executable. You have to update your `PATH`.

(Assuming Windows 7)

Right-click on Computer, the Properties, the Advanced system settings, then click the Environment Variables... button.

The lower window has the system variables. Scroll down until you find Path, select it, and click edit. In the screen that appears, update the path that is pointing to your original python.exe to the one that is in the anaconda path.

Close any open command window for update to take effect.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it wasn't working because I didn't restart my cmd window after making the changes. Rookie mistake!

Comment: Are you sure this is a good solution? Anaconda might do several other init tasks besides modifying path.

Answer (score 7):

From the docs (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/

```
source <path to conda>/bin/activate
conda init
```

"
**Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?**

We do not recommend adding Anaconda to the PATH manually. During installation, you will be asked “Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?” We recommend “yes”. If you enter “no”, then conda will not modify your shell scripts at all. In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run source /bin/activate and then run conda init.
"

Comment: or for windows: `<path to conda>\condabin\activate.bat` then `conda init`

Comment: This doesn't add python to path (at least for Windows). If you follow these steps and start a command prompt, then `python <something>` will still point to the previous instance or will be an unrecognized command, if you didn't have python in the first place.